# Undefined variable: meta_keyword

Tags: php, html, opencart, opencart2.3

I am using opencart 2.3.0.2 on xampp and I have this issue when I load the language file to the view it doesn't work here's the controller C:\xampp\htdocs\opencart2302\catalog\controller\product\categorieslist.php:

```
<?php 
class ControllerProductCategoriesList extends Controller {
    public function index(){
        $this->load->language('product/categorieslist');

        $data = array();

        $data['test'] = "this is text from controller";

        $this->response->setOutput($this->load->view('product/categorieslist',$data));
    }
    // public function add(){
    //     echo "this is add method call from CPC";
    // }
}
```

?>

and here's the language file
C:\xampp\htdocs\opencart2302\catalog\language\en-gb\product\categorieslist.php :

```
 <?php 
//Text
$_['title']             = 'All Categories';
$_['meta_title']        = 'All Categories';
$_['meta_description']  = 'All Categories';
$_['meta_keyword']      = 'All Categories';
$_['categories_text']   = 'This is categories list page 2';
```

and here's the view file C:\xampp\htdocs\opencart2302\catalog\view\theme\default\template\product\categorieslist.tpl :

```
 <?php echo $meta_keyword; ?>
<?php echo $test; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your controller file you must define `meta_keyword`

after

```
$data['test'] = "this is text from controller";
```

add

```
$data['meta_keyword'] = $this->language->get('meta_keyword');
```

Comment: Yes that did worked,  I was watching a video about opencart module development and the guy didn't actually do that he was using opencart 3.0.2.0 he want straight to twig file and he just print {{ meta_keyword }}